# Read local file to parse into HTML using electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I would like to be able to read a local csv file and parse it into the HTML so as to show its contents automatically upon opening an application created in electron

However I am not able to find any way to do so. Using 'fs' to open the file I have no way to pass the contents into the HTML window. Hence I am not sure what to do.

If I use a client side javascript FileReader object then I physically have to drag and drop the file after opening the application.

Is there no way for me to open the application, have it read the local file in the current directory automatically and somehow pass the contents to the html so that it can be read.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I'm using an XMLHttpRequest to get the file contents from the local directory.